# Getting error while signing the android app bundle in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore $(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/resources/keystore.jks -storepass $(keystore-password)
  -keypass $(key-password-stage) app-stage-release-signed.aab $(key-alias-stage)
```

> **Getting error:-** syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Answer (score 0):

> Getting error while signing the android app bundle in azure devops

Just like the error log shows, there must be a syntax error near unexpected token `)` in your command line.

Since we do not have the detailed info about the command line, we could not give you a very accurate error location, you need double check your command line, make sure there is no any syntax error. To verify it, you could signing the android app bundle with this command line on your local machine instead of Azure devops.

Besides, you could replace the variable with the actual value directly, so that we could exclude syntax errors from variables.

You could check the document [jarsigner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) for some more details.

Hope this helps.